# How to translate button english to spanish with php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

so I have this code below that is showing on my career page.
I have a title content on the left and on the right, a button, and when clicking on it, it shows the full content of the article.

```
function myWebsite_careers_function() {
    $markup = '';
    
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'career',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'orderby' => 'post_date', 
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if ($loop->found_posts > 0) {
        $markup .= '<div class="container">';
        
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            $link = get_the_permalink();
        
            $markup .= '<div class="row pt-3 pb-3">';
            $markup .= '<div class="col-8">';
            $markup .= '<h4><a href="' . $link . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>,<br>' . get_field( "location" ) . '</h4>';
            $markup .= '</div>';
            $markup .= '<div class="col-4">';
            $markup .= '<h4 style="text-align: right;"><a href="' . $link . '">' . __("learn more", "myWebsite") . '</a></h4>';
            $markup .= '</div>';
            $markup .= '</div>';
        endwhile;
        
        wp_reset_postdata();
        
        $markup .= '</div>';
    }
    
    return $markup;
}

add_shortcode( 'myWebsite_careers', 'myWebsite_careers_function' );
```

I can translate all my content except the button "learn-more" (code upper).
I would like to know how to get "aprende más" instead of "learn more" when it is in the Spanish version.
I hope you can help me with that, thank you in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Google `Translate Functions of WordPress Plugins 2023`. Is your myWebsite-es_ES.mo loaded within your snippet (plugin)? Is your myWebsite-es_ES.mo in proper directory? (wp-content/languages/plugins/ I think)

Comment: Hi Jasom Dotnet, thank you for your answer, for the first question I suppose yes because it s works on other pages.
For the second question, I have to check that.
I'll let you know if it works.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, the code upper looks good, right?

Comment: Yes, upper code looks ok. What about the string itself? Is it present in .po file? Is it translated?

Comment: So below is button "aswer own question"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was in my WPML plugin, so I clicked on "theme and plugins localization" and then scanned my theme => string translation => and search the string in the list. Translate and its work. thank you for your help cheers! –